# Using puts to print a space (directive, not the character)

Tags: assembly, x86

I have a space

```
buf:    .space 64
```

And I intend to add characters to buf and call puts to print everything in buf, like this

```
movq    $'1', buf
incq    buf
movq    $'2', buf
decq    buf
movq    $buf, %rdi
call    puts
```

The problem is that it only prints out the 1 character and not the 2 as well. How can I print all characters in buf?

Comment: The problem is not with the printing, it's with setting the elements. `movq` is 64 bits and `incq buf` isn't doing what you want either. Do `movb '1', buf; movb '2', buf+1`

Comment: Thanks, that does it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved by doing

```
movb    $'1', buf
movb    $'2', buf+1
movq    $buf, %rdi
call    puts
```

As Jester suggested